# In NiFi how do you send binary files to HTTP Rest?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have following business need. Can anybody please suggest me NiFi WorkFlow I should create? Thanks
1) Through Kakfa I get metadata as JSON Object. This JSON Object has an image or video which is in binary format. This binary file is pretty huge.
2) I need to extract binary data and send it to HTTP rest (POST).

In my mind I have following workflow:
ConsumeKakfa==>EvaluateJsonPath==>UpdateAttributes=>InvokeHTTP

Explanation:
1) ConsumeKakfa will receives metadata as json object.
2) EvaluateJsonPath will extract content json attribute which has image or video data stored as base64.
3) UpdateAttribute will update the flowfile to insert POST payload.
4) InvokeHTTP will invoke POST HTTP rest call.

I am not sure whether huge data will be handle by InvokeHTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your flow should be like this:

- `ConsumeKafka`
- `EvaluateJsonPath (destination=content)` stores evaluated base64 binary into flowfile content
- `Base64EncodeContent (decode)` decodes base64 content into a binary
- `InvokeHTTP` sends everything in content as a body